# Java equivalent to PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: java, html, dom

Since I have to multithread which I can not eloquently solve in PHP I would like to programm in Java, unfortunately I could not finde a library which will allow me to parse a HTML DOM as robustly, quickly and easily as in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. Do you know alternatives in Java that are as easy to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went from Simple HTML DOM Parser to [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) and I'm quite happy with it.

Comment: While looking deeper I just found that one and it shows off quite nice list of features and APIs. Finding elements by CSS selectors is quite nifty.

Comment: On a first glance the functionality of JSoup even seems to exceed the functionality of PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. Now I will compare it to the second suggesion TagSoup, any pros and cons on this?

Comment: The approach with TagSoup, W3C DOM and DOM4J/JDOM should work, but is more complex than JSoup seams to be. I'll give it a try as well, as the project looks very good to me from the description.

Answer (score 3):

I can see that we have two challenges here:

- Parsing of HTML that might not be well-formed XHTML that ease any and nice to parse. I'd recommend [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup) library that can read ugly HTML and produce well-formed StaX stream that can be then used elsewhere.
- Building of DOM representaion of HTML document and dealing with that. As you probably know in JDK there is full-blown implementation of XML DOM (`org.w3c.dom.*`). But I guess this is not the type of API you've been looking for. What about [DOM4J](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net) or older [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org) that can wrap JDK Document and you can enjoy easy to use API?

Comment: I was looking for option one, parsing htm that **is never** really well formed in real life. Accessing the XML DOM with XPATH is really tricky and I just failed coding bullet proof code. TagSoup seems to be a good suggestion, now the question is what suits me better JSoup or TagSoup.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used TagSoup as a SAX parser to populate DOM4J Documents which I then query with XPath. It took me a while to work out the incantations - (Scala, but I'm sure that you can convert):

```
parserFactory = new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.jaxp.SAXFactoryImpl
val reader = new SAXReader(parserFactory.newSAXParser.getXMLReader)
val doc = reader.read(new InputSource(new StringReader(page)))
```

Answer (score 0):

JSoup is a good choice. Here is an example which clears HTML from elements using certain CSS classes and from comments: it's very simple.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;

...

public String cleanHtml(String htmlText) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlText);
    doc.select(".infobox").remove();
    doc.select(".mw-editsection").remove();
    doc.select(".hatnote").remove();
    doc.select(".catlinks").remove();
    doc.select(".noprint").remove();
    doc.select(".metadata").remove();
    doc.select(".toc").remove();
    doc.select("style").remove();
    doc.select("script").remove();
    doc.select("figure").remove();
    doc.select("*[style*=display:none]").remove();
    removeComments(doc);

    return doc.html();
}

private static void removeComments(Node node) {
    node.childNodes().stream().filter(n -> "#comment".equals(n.nodeName())).forEach(Node::remove);
    node.childNodes().forEach(WikipediaCommons::removeComments);
}
```